# So Javascript libraries come with GUI already?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

I'm starting to get a little bit into web development after only stepping into some "desktop-oriented" programming languages.

This is what I don't get:

Until now everytime I've dealt with GUI I needed to get some library that was specifically made to make GUI (qt, gtk, javaFX, etc). Any other library was just pre-written code to help me with something (whatever it was, databases, math, etc). Then I would have to come with a way to use the GUI and those libraries "together".

In javascript I've heard of ways to get into making GUI, like React, Vue, Angular... (which aren't really libraries as far as I know) but somehow I have come across supposedly "normal" libraries that appear to have some GUI embedded into them, without using any of those frameworks that I've mentioned above.

Take this as an example:
[https://quilljs.com](https://quilljs.com/)

This is a text editor library, in which I only have to write some stuff on my html page to get it into my project

```
<script>
  var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: { toolbar: '#toolbar' },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

And then, somehow, a whole real text editor appears, without me ever touching on a GUI framework. This is not even a React component or something like that. I don't understand, how can they come up with this without using a GUI library/framework?

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvLT2.png)

Sorry if this is a extremely simple question, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I wouldn't call Qt, GTK, JavaFX or WPF as "libraries" - they're better described as _platforms_ or _frameworks_. Similarly, Angular and Vue also fit that description (as for React, that's another question).

Comment: They're Frameworks not platforms.

Comment: Remember that components like `Quill` build on-top of HTML+CSS which already provides a substantial UI framework and platform without any JavaScript at all.

Comment: @Adriani6 Thank you - I've updated my comment - but the terms are not strictly-defined in software-engineering and sometimes the differences between what constitutes a platform or a framework are splitting-hairs (e.g. Win32's MFC).

Comment: Totally agreed. It's a bit... opinion-based :).